# Libgdx Issue with rendering mesh

Tags: java, libgdx, rendering, game-development

I am having an issue with rendering a mesh and using the shaders.
I had it working previously, but I have been doing some refactoring for better control over the data, and now it is doing some funky things. It looks like either the vertices are being set weird, or the camera matrix is doing something weird with where the vertices are rendered on screen.

My vertex shader is extremely simple right now.

```
attribute vec4 a_color;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 vColor;

void main() {
    vColor = vec4(.5,.5,.5,.8);
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * vec4(a_position.x,a_position.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here is an example of position and color data (though right now I am just ignoring the color data in the shader)

```
[960.0, 980.0, -1.0, 980.0, 970.0, -1.0, 980.0, 960.0, -1.0]
[960.0, 980.0, -1.0, 980.0, 960.0, -1.0, 960.0, 960.0, -1.0]
```

Each row is a triangle, with 3 vertices (2 position components, and 1 color)

Here is how I am setting up the mesh and the vertex attributes

```
mesh = new Mesh(true, withShaderData.length, 0,
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.Position, POSITION_COMPONENTS, "a_position"),
                new VertexAttribute(VertexAttributes.Usage.ColorPacked, COLOR_COMPONENTS, "a_color"));
mesh.setVertices(withShaderData);
```

When I render this mesh it looks like this.

[image]
It should look like a simple cave system, and it should only fill in 1 of those purple squares. I know the generation code is working correctly because it was working just a bit ago, but I have been refactoring to give myself more control of the mesh, and now I can't figure out what is happening.

This picture shows a zoomed in version.
[image]

As you can see from this image, the edges are overlapping, which shouldn't be the case with the data I have.

Does anybody have any suggestions on why its not rendering correctly?
I have made sure that the data is properly formatted, at least I think I am.
I made sure the shader isn't doing anything crazy.
But it is still rendering the triangles in weird locations.

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I was being stupid. I thought I had formatted it correctly, but I found out I had 1 thing that was completely wrong with my formatting.